# Is there a finite or at worst recursive axiomatization of the theory of the rationals and reals combined?

Tags: model-theory, ordered-fields

Consider the 2-element set $\{(\mathbb{Q};+,-,*,0,1,<),(\mathbb{R};+,-,*,0,1,<)\}$. What is an axiomatization of the theory of that set of structures? Meaning, what is an axiomatization of the set of sentences true of both the rational and the real ordered field? Is there a finite or at worst recursive axiomatization?

Comment: Since $\Bbb N$ is definable in $\Bbb Q$ (as an ordered field!) its axiomatization is not recursive.

Comment: Given structures $\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B}$, the intersection of theories $Th(\mathfrak{A})\cap Th(\mathfrak{B})$ is always at least as complicated as each structure's theory individually: if $\mathfrak{A}\models\varphi$ and $\mathfrak{B}\models\neg\varphi$, then $\varphi\rightarrow\psi\in Th(\mathfrak{A})\cap Th(\mathfrak{B})$ iff $\psi\in Th(\mathfrak{A})$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Perhaps you can answer the question, along with the proof that it is non-recursive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given structures $\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B}$, the intersection of theories $Th(\mathfrak{A})\cap Th(\mathfrak{B})$ is always at least as complicated as each structure's theory individually: WLOG we have $\mathfrak{A}\not\equiv\mathfrak{B}$, but in that case (for example) fixing $\varphi$ such that $\mathfrak{A}\models\varphi$ and $\mathfrak{B}\models\neg\varphi$ we have $$\varphi\rightarrow\psi\in Th(\mathfrak{A})\cap Th(\mathfrak{B})\iff\psi\in Th(\mathfrak{A}).$$ In fact, the [many-one degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-one_reduction) of $Th(\mathfrak{A})\cap Th(\mathfrak{B})$ is the least upper bound of the many-one degrees of $Th(\mathfrak{A})$ and $Th(\mathfrak{B})$. (The same result holds with "$\cup$" in place of "$\cap$," by a similar construction.)

Now in your particular example, since [$\mathbb{N}$ is definable in the field of rationals](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/%7Enies/Students/YanKRobinsonEssay.pdf) we have that $Th(\mathbb{Q};+,\times)$ is not computable; consequently $Th(\mathbb{Q};+,\times)\cap Th(\mathbb{R};+,\times)$ is not computable. (On the other hand $Th(\mathbb{R};+,\times)$ is computable by [Tarski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_of_first-order_theories_of_the_real_numbers).)